# WCF data service Execute sproc using wrong oData protocol version

Tags: c#, .net, odata, wcf-data-services

So i have a WCF data service up and running with .Net 4.5, EF6 & WCF data services 5.6 and have the following in InitializeService

```
    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
        config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.All);
        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
        config.UseVerboseErrors = true;
    }
```

I have a .Net mvc app which i've added a service reference too and everything appears to be working and accessible, however when i try and return a collection of complex types i get the following error:

```
Collection types are only supported in version 3.0 of the OData protocol and higher versions. They are not supported in version 1.0.
```

I've also noticed that my service.edmx has dataService v1:

```
<edmx:DataServices m:DataServiceVersion="1.0" m:MaxDataServiceVersion="3.0" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
```

I've tested the service url with the below sproc and parameters in Fiddler and i can see it's using serviceVersion 1.0 in the header however when i try and use a var for the parameters it throws the above exception.

```
string querystring = string.Format("GetSecurityIdByName?securityName='{0}'", maincompany.Name);
                IEnumerable<get_security_id_by_name_Result> getsecurityid = context.Execute<get_security_id_by_name_Result>(new Uri(querystring, UriKind.Relative), "GET", false);
```

What am i missing? How can i force it / execute the sproc using v3?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, sending the correct version via SendingRequest2() fixed the issue, but feels hacky and not the "proper" solution. Perhaps it's still a known bug as per this post my a Microsoft employee from 2012!

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3a735526-59a9-494d-9240-7107e1ccceae/return-iqueryable-of-dtos-from-serviceoperation?forum=adodotnetdataservices

```
context.SendingRequest2 += (sender, eventArgs) => {
    eventArgs.RequestMessage.SetHeader("MinDataServiceVersion", "3.0;NetFx");
};
```

Comment: I had to add this call as well when the IEnumerable being returned from the OData service was empty. It still feels hacky.